# Error with signing jar files using jarsigner with a real certificate

Tags: java

I have a problem with signing my jar files with jarsigner. I used [this](http://serialize.wordpress.com/2007/08/14/signing-a-jar-file-with-spc-and-pvk-file/) tutorial to sign my jar files, but with the last step(signing the jar), I got this error:

> jarsigner error: java.lang.RuntimeException: keystore load: Invalid keystore format

and I didn't use step #10, I used instead step #5 from [this](http://wiki.plexinfo.net/index.php?title=How_to_sign_JAR_files) site since, I'm using a real certificate not a fake one ...

Note:
I'm having my certificate in `.spc` & `.pvk` format...

But, since I'm using jarsigner, I have to convert them to `.p12` format. So, I convert them first to `.pfx` using `pvkimprt.exe` then to `.p12`. I used the method that I specified in the link that I mentioned it before.

Also, I tried to create a fake certificate to make sure that the problem is not from the `pvkimprt.exe` tool or from the certificate. It gave me the same error.

The certificate is just fine. So, where is the problem came from?

Answer (score 3):

The error you are facing indicates that jarsigner does not understand the format of the keystore containing the key.

If you converted your key & certificate into a PKCS#12 file you have to specify the type of used keystore to jarsigner with the `-storetype PKCS12` command line option and the P12 password with `-storepass mystorepassword`

(actually most of the time .pfx and .p12 are used for the same file format therefore I am not sure that the firefox import/export step in the tutorial is mandated)

Comment: Nothing new... Also, it gave me the same error message... I don't know why :(

Comment: In order to check that your p12 is not corrupted did you try to read your p12 file with openssl or keytool? keytool -list -v -keystore myfile.p12 -storetype pkcs12 -storepass password

Comment: it gave me this error when i use the keytool command: "keytool error: java.io.IOException: failed to decrypt safe contents entry: javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Given final block not properly padded" but what is wrong ??
 the ".spc & "pvk" are fine and working... and I don't think its from them. since also, when i create fake certificate it gave the same error ... so, is it from the jarsigner it self ?? Do you know another tool that easy to use and can do the same job ??

Answer (score 2):

Not really an answer, just a comment - I found that the upper case was crucial - "pkcs12" didn't work but "PKCS12" did, using Jcs's answer.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I did and that worked:

```
<ant:signjar alias="le-f0b73c88-1f82-4497-8c3f-e10d399b4c9c" storetype="pkcs12"
   storepass="fount-current"  
   keystore="/vobs/oam_base/loadbuild_tools/common/src/conf/kunal.pfx">
```

Store pass should be the lower case, this is the working order or arguments, some time wrong order with throw the runtime padding exception.

> [signjar] jarsigner error: java.lang.RuntimeException: keystore load:

Comment: This is the ant piece of code, <ant:signjar alias="le-f0b73c88-1f82-4497-8c3f-e10d399b4c9c" storetype="pkcs12" storepass="fount-current" keystore="/vobs/oam_base/loadbuil
d_tools/common/src/conf/kunal.pfx">